# Остаток от деления суммы элементов матрицы

Tags: алгоритм, математика, матрицы

Есть две матрицы:

```
A - размера [1xN]
B - размера [N*N]
```

Выполняются следующие вычисления `A*B*B*...*B` (умножение происходит k раз).

Получается результирующая матрица

```
 С - размера [1xN]
```

В этой матрице необходимо просуммировать все элементы и найти остаток от деления  полученной суммы на `m`. То есть

```
C = { c1, c2, ... , cn }
S = c1+c2+...+cn
result = S % m
```

В условиях задачи сумма S может быть сколь угодно велика. То есть имеется ввиду, что вычислять значение S не нужно, ведь от задачи требуется найти лишь остаток от деления.

Находил в интернете "Возведение матрицы в степень по модулю". Но не совсем понимаю, что является остатком от деления матрицы на число.

Подскажите, в ту ли сторону копаю, и применим ли этот метод для моей задачи.

Comment: *>>что является остатком от деления матрицы на число* --Нужно же не матрицу на число делить, а сумму матрицы, т.е. *число/число*. Если сумма может быть очень большая и выходить за пределы аппаратных возможностей: суммировать 2 элемента (сумма *S*). Если *S>m*, то* S=остаток+следующий элемент*. Иначе *S=S+следующий элемент*. Продолжать в цикле.

Comment: Ну это в рамках моей задачи. А я находил алгоритмы "Возведения матрицы в степень по модулю". Мне показалось, что это что-то похожее. Вот и упомнил. А возведение матрицы в степень по модулю это (A^k)%m, так ведь? Т.е. матрица/число

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Умножение матриц (+сложение элементов) используют только две операции - умножения и сложения. Обе позволяют использовать модуль при выполнении:

```
(n+k)%m = (n%m+k%m)%m
(n*k)%m = (n%m)*(k%m)%m
```

Так что вы просто при умножениях матриц, не допуская переполнений, срезаете получающиеся элементы по модулю. Как и при суммировании элементов последней матрицы.

Что до умножений/делений матриц на скаляр, то это - [поэлементное умножение/деление](http://www.webmath.ru/poleznoe/formules_6_4.php).